# How can I call a listener which monitors all events in angularjs? Like mouseover and focus events for all input types.

Tags: angularjs

How can I call a listener which monitors all events in angularjs? Like single function for mouseover and focus events which toggles classes for the element.

Answer (score 0):

I see 4 ways, only the 1st one is easy, but quite repetitive :

First :

1. with an app.run bind your function "myFN" with the $rootScope
2. for all input add all the event you want to handle

Second : if you use the route module from angular or the ui-router only

Listen for $routeChangeSuccess (or $stateChangeSuccess if using ui-router) then use angular.element to get all inputs and bind all your events. If you do that don't use the ng-if directives or it won't work.

Third

Create a directive that will contains input attributes (name, mg-model, id;type,...) and replace itself with an input from which you will have add all the event binding that you need (so it will generate pretty much the same HTML as the 1st solution in the end).

Fourth

Decorate the input directive from angular, listen for each event and use the $rootScope.$emit() to emit an event that will contains all informations you need (type of event, which input,...).